# How to change default PHP path used by cron

Tags: php, path, cron

I'm using a cron job that runs a PHP script like this:

```
* * * * * php /path/to/script schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

But is running with older version of PHP. When I run `which PHP` I get `/path/to/php7.0`, and I need to change the path used by cron to run PHP. Is this possible without specifying it in cron job like this?

```
* * * * * /path/to/php7.0 /path/to/script schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: just edit the cron job

Answer (score 0):

You can used symbolic link.

Remove the current php executable file

Then.

```
ln -s /path/to/php7.0 php (location of php executable file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your "new" php path to the system `$PATH` variable by editing `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` file:

`export PATH=/path/to/php7.0:$PATH`

(replace `/path/to/php7.0` with your actual `php` path)